# line graphs - mysql php and .js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I'm doing a uni project.
I have sensor readings from a train (multiple censors)
Each sensor in contained in its own table, connected to train ID, date, time and readings.

The constant is time as each reading from the sensor is out putting at different ranges.

(I'm looking for spikes in the line graph, and want to overlay various lines to compare spikes and dips in time.)

I want to create a line graph (which I can do with a single table) but I'm running into problems when a overlay engine RPM with lets say power usage.

RPM is 0 - 5000
power usage is 0-100

Any thoughts or help

Thanks guys.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what types of problems you're running into?

Comment: I need to overlay the 2,3, or 5 line graphs into one.
There y axis don't match.
It's only to create a visual for engineers to look for spikes and dips

Comment: Ok, the y-axis isn't matching like it should. Could you include a screenshot of your current graph? And maybe an edited on of what you expect, if that isn't too hard.

Comment: I'll come back to this tomorrow -